# Looking for vehicle that uses this 3-pin connector

Tags: electrical

I need to order this automotive connector for a hot water circulation pump (HVAC), but the "Mini Superseal" series connector, TE part number 1879978-1 does not appear to exist.  The closest I can find is https://www.te.com/usa-en/product-1879980-1.html, but it is not in stock anywhere, has a 1-year lead time, and a minimum order quantity of 15,000 pieces.  I need two.

[image: Automotive 3-pin Mini Super Seal Connector]
[image: Dimensions]

Any idea what vehicle this could be used in since I suspect I can find the part that way.  The local auto parts stores haven't been able to figure it out so far.

### Update

The receiving side of the connector is molded into the pump, so I cannot change it.  This is a pump for a building heating system, but it uses automotive connectors for the 10V control signals.

The pump manufacturer is out of stock as well.

Here is a picture of the receiving side.

[image: Mating Connector Side View]
[image: Mating Connector Pin View]

Comment: Can't you just change the connector for a commonly available one?

Comment: Can you give a bit of background as to what you are trying to do?

Comment: Is it really an automotive device?  The colours of those wires are UK mains colours.  Brown - Live, Blue - Neutral and Yellow/Green - Earth.  Is it mains powered?

Comment: What kind of vehicle has a hot water circulation pump? Even motor homes don't have those.

Comment: @HandyHowie - not sure how much better I can describe this.  I need an automotive connector for a pump.  Connector is not available through electronics distributors or the pump manufacturer.  If I can find out which vehicle uses this connector, I may be able to get one through automotive channels.

Comment: @GdD.  You are missing the point, the question is what vehicle uses this connector.

Comment: How hard have you actually shopped?  Newark has it https://www.newark.com/te-connectivity/1879980-1/automotive-housing-conn-plug-3pos/dp/92AH6714?st=. Prepare to receive a connector with empty voids and you add the pins.  They should sell those too. Also have you tried talking to humans, or are you only googling?

Comment: Yes, I saw Newark had the shell in the UK and Digikey has the female socket pins presumably in the USA, but I'm looking at 1.5 to 2 weeks to receive those in New Zealand and if I can find an equivalent pig-tail connector at the local auto parts store by tomorrow, I can save 18 hours of travel back to the job site.

Comment: @eric I'm guessing you don't spend an outsize amount of time shopping for auto parts LOL.   Auto parts stores carry very little selection in connectors, just the most common ones. If you identify a car the connector is used on, you'd go to a "you pull it" yard and snip it off the wiring harness of a wreck.

Comment: "If you identify a car the connector is used on" -- yes, that is why I posted this question.

Answer (score 1):

The pin size and arrangement looks very similar to BMW motorcycle part no. 83300402341, Repair Plug (3-pin), seen as item no. 6 on the K27 (factory type number) parts fiche [here](https://www.realoem.com/bmw/enUS/showparts?id=0398-USA---K27-BMW-R%201200%20R%2006%20(0378,0398)&diagId=61_2484). Here's an image from that page of the real.oem reproduction of the fiche:

[image]

The size and shape of the oval seem the same. The register shape close around the three connectors is different, but it's the closest I could come up with. Might fit, might not.

The part is found on [many BMW motorcycles](https://www.realoem.com/bmw/enUS/part?id=0398-USA---K27-BMW-R%201200%20R%2006%20(0378,0398)&mg=61&sg=13&diagId=61_2484&q=83300402341).

Comment: Thank you.  I haven't checked at motorcycle shops yet and will give that a try.  I think #5 is bigger than the one I'm looking for, but half the battle is finding out where these show up with vehicle part numbers instead of OEM part numbers.

Comment: @Eric Plug #5 is bigger, but it has four contacts instead of the three you're looking for.